# Javascript List Button Not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a list button to update a status field on a list of records, but I have problems with the syntax.  Please help..

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 

var url = parent.location.href; 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Tasks__c )}; 

var updateRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else { 

for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { 

    var update_Tasks = new sforce.SObject("{!Tasks__c}"); 
    update_{!Tasks__c.Id} = records[a]; 

    update_{!Tasks__c.Status__c} = "Completed"; 
    updateRecords.push(update_Tasks__c); 

    }
    result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 

    parent.location.href = url; 
}
```

Error is in the {!GETRECORDIDS ($ObjectType....  I am using a custom object and not sure how to write it.

Comment: Try using the label of the object instead.

Comment: @PepeFloyd  Thanks for replying.  I tried replacing the Tasks__c with just the label which is "Customer Tasks" but it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting at the line containing `GETRECORDIDS()`?

Comment: @MarkPond Hi... it says "Field Customer_Tasks" does not exist.  I changed it from API Name I had before to Label.  Thnks!

Comment: What error are you getting with the code the way you posted it? Also, this line you do not need them markup tag: new sforce.SObject("{!Tasks__c}"); and I am not sure what you are doing here update_{!Tasks__c.Id} = records[a];  update_{!Tasks__c.Status__c} = "Completed";

Comment: @CyberJus... I have apparently made a mess of things.  I get the same error the way it was posted and only made a suggested change (which had the same resulting error).  I am trying to update a pick list field value when the button is clicked from a list view on my custom object.

Error is Field Tasks__c does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure your custom object is not called Task__c and not Tasks__c? Object names are typically supposed to be singular.  Also, look at @MarkPond answer for some of the other items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object names look fine but you've got merge syntax `{! }` in your javascript that shouldn't be there. I've modified your javascript variables in the code below to make it a bit clearer what is happening in the loop. You may still have field API name issues to clear up.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 

var url = parent.location.href; 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Tasks__c)}; 

var recordsToUpdate = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
    alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else { 

    for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { 

        var taskToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("{!Tasks__c}"); 
        taskToUpdate.Id = records[a]; 

        taskToUpdate.Status__c = "Completed"; 
        recordsToUpdate.push(taskToUpdate); 

        }

    var result = sforce.connection.update(recordsToUpdate); 

    // you probably want to check what is in 'result' and look for success before 
    // redirecting the browser to the new URL

    parent.location.href = url; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am clearly missing a piece of the puzzle, so I'll try to figure it out based on the comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mark's answer, the final piece of the puzzle is that your sObject creation syntax is not quite right.

You don't need `{!}` at this point.

Change `var taskToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("{!Tasks__c}");`

To `var taskToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Tasks__c");`

The curly bracket syntax is a static way to tell salesforce that you want the value in the curly bracket to be replaced with some actual value. In this case, you don't want that - you want to create an object of type "Tasks__c"